# How can user quit full screen in phaser.js?

Tags: javascript, fullscreen, game-development, phaser-framework

I have a game that automatically plays in full screen with

```
this.scale.startFullscreen();
```

and i want to give a user an option to quit full screen by pressing 'x' in top right corner. So i wrote:

```
this.add.text(750, 20, 'X', { fontSize: '20px'});

this.exitFullScreen = this.add.rectangle(770, 30, 60, 60, 0xfff);

this.exitFullScreen.setInteractive();

this.exitFullScreen.on('pointerup', this.scale.stopfullScreen);
```

but that doesn't work, i also tried putting `this.scale.stopfullScreen` inside a callback function and i also added conditional `if (isFullscreen())`, but that didn't work either. Is there any way i can give user an option to quit full screen, ideally without removing `this.scale.startFullscreen();` at the beginning of `create()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line `this.exitFullScreen.on('pointerup', this.scale.stopfullScreen);` the eventlistener *`.on('pointerup', ...)`* calls the passed callback function with a different context.

Just change the eventlistener to `.on('pointerup', () => this.scale.stopFullscreen());` and it should work.
***Or*** you could pass the correct context *(for the function)* as third parameter to the eventlistener, like this: `.on('pointerup', this.scale.stopFullscreen, this.scale);`

Comment: Yes, you were right again, thanks! thought i tried that, clearly i didn't.